# Saving data with Unity and Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, persistent-data

I have been trying to save game data using a binary formatter and Application.persistentDataPath on my Tango device. After saving however, the file is nowhere to be found. 
Right now the path is reading out as "Storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mine.project/files/filename.bin", but as stated above, the path doesn't actually exist anywhere.
Is there another way to save all of this data on the Tango that I have yet to find? If not, is there a way to get these files to show up?
This is the code that I am currently using, minus some debugging functions I use.

> ```
> string path = Application.persistentDataPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "file.bin";   
> BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();    
> FileStream file = File.Open (path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);  
> bf.Serialize(file, data); 
> file.Close ();
> ```

From what I can tell this isn't throwing any errors, I can even find the file again via the File.Exists() function, but I need to find the file again for access through other programs, and so far it has proven impossible.

Comment: Show a relevant code sample for your save operation.

Comment: Is it important that your application write data to the persistent data path? Would it work for you to write to SD card?  

If you are attempting to read back the information on your computer, it is easier to deal with data stored on the SD card.

Comment: Ideally yes, I would be reading the information back on my computer. I don't have a SD card currently, but as soon as I do I planned on giving that a try, was hoping to figure it out before then though.

Comment: Strangely, I pulled the cord out of the Tango and the data saved directly to the tango's storage(not a SD card). I had tried it before, but it wouldn't save. No idea what happened. Glad it is working though, thanks guys.